# What is the IBU cutoff between a Pale Ale and an IPA?

Tags: ipa, ibu

Granted these are different techniques, there seems to be a line where Pale Ales start to become more bitter and hoppy and IPA-esque.  The thing is that Pale Ales don't usually list thier IBU on the bottle.

Hence the question; does anyone know about where Pale Ales end and IPAs begin, with regard to bitterness at least?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Referring to the [BJCP Style Guidelines](http://www.bjcp.org/2008styles/catdex.php), the following is true:

[English Pale Ales (ESBs)](http://www.bjcp.org/2008styles/style08.php): 25-50 IBUs

[American Pale Ales](http://www.bjcp.org/2008styles/style10.php): 20-40 IBUs

[IPAs](http://www.bjcp.org/2008styles/style14.php): 40-60 IBUs for English, 40-70 IBUs for American, 60-120 IBUs for Imperial IPAs

Based on this, the answer to your question should be in the 40+ IBU range to differentiate bitterness between pale ales and IPAs.

Bear in mind these are guidelines and not gospel. Generally, the BJCP style guide is a great starting point.

Comment: These are fairly dated #s.  Its true its what BJCP states now but it seems funny to think of an IPA with an IBU as low as 40.  Are these #s changing with the newer BJCP guidelines?  Anyone know?

Comment: There seem to be some differences int he draft 2014 BJCP guideline document. E.g. American Pale Ale is now 30-50 IBU instead of 20-40 IBU. http://www.bjcp.org/docs/2014%20BJCP%20Style%20Guidelines%20(DRAFT).pdf

Comment: IPAs (English and American) are keeping their IBU range in the draft version. So, you can see IPAs inside the range of APA and English PAs.